# Power TV on/off

Tags: raspbian, xorg, server

I'm looking for a solution to wake up my LCD TV.

With the `xset` command I'm able to put the TV in different power saving modes:

```
xset dpms force standby

xset dpms 0 30 60
```

0 = standby

30 sec = suspend

60 sec = off

I need a solution to wake the TV up from these mode. So far with the:

```
xset dpms force on
```

I'm not able to do wake it up.

I want the TV to switch on 07.00 every morning and off 17.00 as a cron job.

These are my default values. Values so that the **PI** keeps the X window up 24/7:

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor"
    Option "DPMS" "false"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "ServerLayout0"
    Option "BlankTime"  "0"
    Option "StandbyTime" "0"
    Option "SuspendTime" "0"
    Option "OffTime" "0"
EndSection
```

Comment: Does your TV support CEC? You need to use HDMI to use it also. I can use CEC from my Pi and other devices to wake everything else up. So if I turn on my VuDuo it turns on the Pi and my Viera TV all in one go using CEC. It does not matter which remote or device I use if I turn one off then the rest go to sleep too.

Comment: I'm connected through the HDMI side. The TV is of a newer PHILIPS model. I'm able to turn the TV off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile libcec

```
apt-get install build-essential autoconf liblockdev1-dev libudev-dev git libtool pkg-config
git clone git://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec.git

cd libcec
./bootstrap
LDFLAGS="-s -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib -L/opt/vc/lib" ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-rpi --with-rpi-include-path=/opt/vc/include --with-rpi-lib-path=/opt/vc/include
make
make install
```

Link the libraries

```
ldconfig
```

Now check if it has found some cec devices.

```
 cec-client -l
```

To turn the TV on you will use the command

```
echo 'on 0' | cec-client -s
```

[You can download the CEC specification here.](http://xtreamerdev.googlecode.com/files/CEC_Specs.pdf)

Comment: The last line after the `./configure` command:
configure: error: Raspberry Pi API not found or incompatible with libCEC

I'm not able to `make` and `make install`.

Comment: ok changed the confiture - there seems to be libraries in different places and it can't find them

Comment: `apt-get install libraspberrypi-dev` is required to full-fill the `./configure`

Comment: I'm able to turn it on with `echo 'on 0' | cec-client -s`. How do I turn it off?

Comment: I couldn't find anything searching `cec-client -s` in that document. But the correct output is `echo 'standby 0' | cec-client -s`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `xset s reset` after `xset dpms force on` will make the screen go on.
It's not a solution since the `xset` command will only blank the TV. The LED lights will still be powered. So it will not literately be in standby mode.