# Put HDMI monitor in Sleep Mode

Tags: hdmi

I have a raspberry pi running Debian. I want to set up a cron script so that the screen automatically goes into *sleep* mode (no power) at a given time and goes out at another time. The built-in screensaver is just blanking the screen, but it's still powered up, and in fact, there's a little lightening bolt in the upper-right hand corner even when the screen is "off".(1)

So what should I do? I've tried installing `xscreensaver` but it doesn't seem to power down the screen or put it in sleep mode. This should be a simple command line thing, but I can't find it.

(1) - Which I just discovered is a BAD THING --- [What does the lightning bolt mean?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57963/what-does-the-lightning-bolt-mean) --- but that's another matter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power TV on/off](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11675/power-tv-on-off)

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight and let you know if it is a duplicate, @DmitryGrigoryev. Thanks.

Comment: Also check out [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22039/turning-on-hdmi-programmatically-doesnt-work)

Comment: Interestingly, it was the question that had the answer, not the answer. It's also not clear, so I will just answer it here.

Answer (score 2):

This command puts it into standby now, suspend in 30 seconds, 60 seconds off:

```
xset dpms 0 30 60
```

This command will blank the display and put it in standby mode immediately:

```
xset dpms force standby
```